# how to write the sql command?

Tags: sql

table one:

```
field one     field two
1               1-1
2               1-2
3               1-5
4               1-3
4               1-6
4              1-2
5              1-0
```

using the sql command to get the results as the following table.

```
field one     field two
5               1-0
1               1-1
2               1-2
4               1-2
4               1-3
4               1-6
3               1-5
```

ps: the condition is selecting  field two  order by asc . but if the result  have the same field one.then  put the field two together. and asc them.

Comment: It is really not clear **what** your desired SQL command needs to return. "Get the results as this order"; is this what you have accomplished so far, or is it what you wish to accomplish?

Comment: `group by` `field one` and `order by` `field two`?doesn't that work?Or vice versa?

Comment: i am sorry, i have updated the question. the table 2 is what i wish to accomplish.

Comment: JohnnyCageWins ,but i don't know how to order fields tow, there is a hyphen in it

Comment: field two in the second table is not ordered numerically ... 1-5 is last, should 1-6 be last ?

Comment: He wants to order by field two, BUT if there is a corresponding field one, put that after the ordered one. So the ordering does not really make sense this way. could we ask why you want to do this?

Comment: there is an order as this: if the field one not the same. the number will ascend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't checked the syntax but something along these lines should do it:

```
select tableOne.fieldOne, tableOne.fieldTwo, b.SortField from tableOne
inner join 
(select fieldOne, min(fieldTwo) as SortField from tableOne group by fieldOne) b
on (b.fieldOne = tableOne.fieldOne)
order by b.SortField, tableOne.fieldOne, tableOne.fieldTwo
```

In essence: for each fieldOne find the lowest value in the group and use that as primary sortfield for all records in the group. Within the group sort on the actual value in fieldtwo

There are still potential issues left though: 1-10 will sort between 1-1 and 1-2 
If you also want to resolve that you need to split up fieldtwo and convert to ints.

In all cases you might want to rethink if this datamodel is really setup the way you want/need

Comment: b.SortField is min(fieldtwo) from the subquery

Comment: It's a temp value that comes from the subselect (aliased as b). You need it to determine the sorting order. I noticed btw that I missed the from statement for both the select and subselect. I'll update them.

Comment: +1 this works (it's only missing a couple of `FROM tableOne` in the two `SELECT`s)

Comment: paolo ,i have tested the command.it's ok. where missed FROM tableOne? thank you

Comment: Eddy,you're my hero, if i want to resolve the potential issues : 1-10 will sort between 1-1 and 1-2, how to do it? and how to  convert the recored to ints. many many thanks

Comment: @zhuanzhou by the time I had finished testing and writing my comment, Eddy had already fixed the code, as he himself notes in his comment. So please disregard what I wrote (except the "+1" part... :) )

Comment: Eddy, what's the meaning of select fieldOne, min(fieldTwo) as SortField from tableOne group by fieldOne .i tested it on phpmyadmin. it gots some records. expcet the repeated fieldone rows. what's the use of min(fieldTwo)? if i deleted the group by part, the result i got is only one row

Comment: It returns for each distinct value of fieldOne the lowest fieldtwo value. By joining it with the whole table it introduces a new column where each record in a group gets an extra value equal to the lowest fieldtwo value in that group (1-2 for all record with fieldone =4). Sorting is than done on that new columns which ensures that all records where fieldOne=4 are together (they all have the same sort value) and that the group is placed between 1-1 and 1-3. The subsequent sorting columns rearrange the records within the group

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your second question (actually sort properly as well) it gets a tad bit more complex.
This version works on Sql-Server (don't know what you are using and the functions may differ)

```
select tableOne.fieldOne, tableOne.fieldTwo
from tableOne
inner join 
   (select 
      fieldOne, 
      MIN(Convert(int, LEFT(tableOne.FieldTwo, CHARINDEX('-', tableOne.fieldTwo)-1))) as LeftPartMin,
      MIN(Convert(int, SubString(tableOne.FieldTwo, CHARINDEX('-', tableOne.fieldTwo)+1, 100))) as RightPartMin
    from tableOne group by fieldOne
   ) b
on (b.fieldOne = tableOne.fieldOne)
order by b.LeftPartMin, b.RightPartMin, fieldOne, Convert(int, LEFT(tableOne.FieldTwo, CHARINDEX('-', tableOne.fieldTwo)-1)), Convert(int, SubString(tableOne.FieldTwo, CHARINDEX('-', tableOne.fieldTwo)+1, 100))
```

You can test this by adding the following 2 records at the end in your table:
4     1-20
2     1-10

This also revealed an error in the first solution: you need to sort one fieldOne as well! (as the second sort argument) to make sure groups with the same fieldOne end up together (edited other answer to correct this)

Comment: Eddy,you're my hero! you datebase skill is gorgeous.up to now,i am not 100% following  the first solution very well. ): i don't know why using inner join.in my memory, i always using it in two tables.